# PYTHON: 2D table - how to return the row of a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported a csv file containing data, this is the first 5 rows:

[first 5 rows of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKKw3.png)

I'm trying to do two things:

1. I want to return a list of all the years in which total crime is below a specific value.

the code I've used provides a boolean response:

```
highcrime = crime["Total Crime"]>25000000
print(highcrime)
```

[output to above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuXgI.png)

Is there a way I can get it to return only the years in which `crime["Total Crime"]>25000000 is TRUE`?

2. I want to search for the year in which total crime is the lowest - I've used a minimum function here:

   `min(new_crime["totalcrime"])`

it returns the lowest value in the column - but I would like it to return the corresponding year to which this value applies.

I've tried doing a number of things, and I get errors or an output which doesn't make sense....

this is the latest attempt:

```
mincrime = new_crime["totalcrime"]<6768321
print(mincrime)
```

[output to above"mincrime"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQQ9A.png)

The output says that totalcrime for every year is TRUE - less than 6768321... this is incorrect, only the minimum value in the column is less than this number. The minimum 6768320.

I just want to be able to get the Year that corresponds to the value 6768320 which is in the column labelled "totalcrime"

I'm new to python so.... PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Welcome to SO. could you please provide your data in a usable form, so it is possible to work with it? Btw. your screenshot for the data and the output are the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the loc function :

```
row_cond=crime.loc[crime['Total Crime']>25000000]
list_year=row_cond['Year']
row2=crime.loc[crime['Total Crime']==crime['Total Crime'].min()]
minyear=row2['Year']
```